# (Some) webfonts not loading through Cloudfront using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm hosting a website on Heroku using Ruby on Rails. It uses a Cloudfront distribution to serve assets, and S3 to store images.

When going to `http://example.com`, everything works fine except for 2 webfonts. All the other fonts load fine.

When going to `http://www.example.com`, none of the webfonts load.

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I was using the normal Cloudfront asset host `d12345.cloudfront.net`, but I figured if I switched to `assets.example.com`, I'd outsmart the CORS issues. But I'm still getting:

```
Access to Font at 'http://assets.example.com/assets/myfont-Bold-735639b52225ec60e258c2b8b193dfb479f6158c3738a595db04f3a9684a4ad8.woff' from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

```

I have read countless threads, blogposts, SO answers about this issue but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have set up Rack::Cors in my rails application as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/assets/*', headers: :any, methods: [:get]
  end
end
```

My asset_host is set up correctly:

```
CLOUDFRONT_HOST = "http://assets.example.com"
config.action_controller.asset_host = CLOUDFRONT_HOST
```

All other assets work perfectly fine. Images, JavaScript, CSS all come from CloudFront without any hiccups. It's just the 2 webfonts when going to the `www.example.com` subdomain and all webfonts when going to the root level site `example.com`.

I have tried a number of options in the Cloudfront and S3 admin panels:

- added cors config to my bucket
- whitelisted headers in my cloudfront distribution

But nothing seems to work. I'm lost as to why those 2 fonts won't load properly while everything else works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fonts are usually checked by your browser preflight, with an `OPTIONS` request. In your CORS setup, try also allowing `OPTIONS` in addition to `GET`. You might also have to allow `OPTIONS` on your CloudFront distribution.

Note that if these fonts have a query parameter in the request url, like `assets.example.com/font.woff?v=123`, the CloudFront distribution should also forward query parameters.